# Fairy castle cactus

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, cactus

My cactus has been suffering for 3 days, and now it look very sick.
Could someone tell me the cause for which it looks like this and how I take care of him?
Thank you very much!
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It either needs water or it's dead. Cactus should be watered when the soil is almost dry, not on an arbitrary schedule.

If it looked fine three days ago and now looks like the picture, it's probably dead. Hard to say what may have killed it. There are no obvious pests. You could dig it up to see if there are still roots.

Have there been any recent changes in environment? Like changing windows, inside/outside, etc. When was it watered last? Has it ever been fertilized?

If it was my plant I'd water it heavily for two days in a row and see what happens. Hopefully some water will perk it up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
3 days ago I noticed that there are small cockroaches in pots and I changed the soil with a special one for cacti and I replanted the plant. I also used an insecticide spray.
I thought he had excess water, so I didn't water him for a week.

Comment: That makes sense. Water it and it should recover. Wait a few days after a repot for the roots to heal and then water sparingly for a week or so. Then back to normal.